# Passing props from one component to another in ReactJS returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I am a newbie in React and I am trying to pass props from one React component to another. Please consider my code below and tell me what could I possibly doing wrong.
As you will notice, I am trying to do so with this.props.value, but all I got in the console is "undefined". I managed to run the code by putting all HTML elements in one component and it was working perfectly fine.

```
class Editor extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      input: defaultTxt
    };
    this.inputChanges = this.inputChanges.bind(this);
  }

  inputChanges(e) {
    this.setState({
      input: e.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="editorBar">
          Editor
          <i className="fa fa-expand expand" />
        </div>
        <textarea
          id="editor"
          style={editorStyle}
          value={this.state.input}
          onChange={this.inputChanges}
          placeholder={defaultTxt}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

//preview

class Previewer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="previewerBar">
          Preview
          <i className="fa fa-expand expand" />
        </div>
        <div
          id="preview"
          style={viewerStyle}
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.props.value }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

//wrapper

class Wrapper extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="wrapper">
        <Editor />
        <Previewer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const defaultTxt = `Some default text`;

ReactDOM.render(<Wrapper />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: If you want to type something in editor and have that appear in preview you really want to have your state/state methods in `Wrapper` if you want to share the state between the two components.

Comment: [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Comment: how did you pass the props to Previewer component? I expected <Previewer value={value} /> kind of thing but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should look like this:

```
class Editor extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="editorBar">
          Editor
          <i className="fa fa-expand expand" />
        </div>
        <textarea
          id="editor"
          style={editorStyle}
          value={this.props.input}
          onChange={this.props.inputChanges}
          placeholder={defaultTxt}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

//preview

class Previewer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="previewerBar">
          Preview
          <i className="fa fa-expand expand" />
        </div>
        <div
          id="preview"
          style={viewerStyle}
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.props.value }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

//wrapper

class Wrapper extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      input: defaultTxt
    };
    this.inputChanges = this.inputChanges.bind(this);
  }

  inputChanges(e) {
    this.setState({
      input: e.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="wrapper">
        <Editor input={this.state.input} inputChanges={this.inputChanges}/>
        <Previewer value={this.state.input}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const defaultTxt = `Some default text`;

ReactDOM.render(<Wrapper />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

The idea is that the `Wrapper component` will be the one which hold the state and control the state change. The Editor and Previewer are its children which receive data to display and invoke the callback prop.

Answer (score 1):

If two components share state lift the state to the parent component - in this case `Wrapper`. And since neither of the two children components have state they can be coded as stateless functions.

```js
function Editor({ text, handleChange }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div id="editorBar">Editor
        <i className="fa fa-expand expand" />
      </div>
      <textarea id="editor" value={text} onChange={handleChange} />
    </div>
  );
}

function Previewer({ text }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div id="previewerBar">Preview
        <i className="fa fa-expand expand"></i>
      </div>
      <div id="preview" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: text}}></div>
    </div>
  );
}

class Wrapper extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={ input: props.defaultText }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ input: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="wrapper">
        <Editor text={this.state.input} handleChange={this.handleChange} />
        <Previewer text={this.state.input} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const defaultText = 'Some default text';

ReactDOM.render(<Wrapper defaultText={defaultText} />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```